# Avoiding overlap when jittering points

Tags: r, plot

When reading scientific papers I often come across plots where points are jittered without overlaping each other. I suspect many of them are drawn with a program called [GraphPad Prism](http://www.graphpad.com/), but surely there must be a way to do the same in R. Although it is not perfect (as with the red points below) I think it looks much better than random jittering.

[image: Jittered points without overlap]

If anybody knows how to do this, preferably using some basic function, I'd be very happy to know.

Comment: this is often called a *beeswarm plot*; there are some functions in the newer versions of ggplot2 that do this

Comment: Ah, nice to get a name on it. Makes it much easier to find out more. I am not that familiar with ggplot (always preferred lattice), but I guess I could always reverse engineer a general function for it.

There seems to be a package called [beeswarm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/beeswarm/index.html) in CRAN that also does it.

Comment: Relevant package for ggplot: https://github.com/eclarke/ggbeeswarm

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a ggplot2 solution using `geom_dotplot()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1234)

dat = data.frame(y=c(rpois(20, 4), rpois(20, 1), runif(20, 0, 20)), 
                category=rep(c("group_1", "group_2", "group_3"), c(20, 20, 20)))

dotplot_1 = ggplot(dat, aes(x=category, y=y)) + 
            geom_dotplot(aes(fill=category), binaxis="y", 
                         stackdir="center", binwidth=0.8) +
            stat_summary(fun.y=median, fun.ymin=median, fun.ymax=median, 
                         geom="crossbar", width=0.7)

ggsave("dotplot_1.png", dotplot_1, width=6, height=4)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that looks nice! And pretty simple too, might even cure my initial confusion over ggplot2 :) I'll stick around for a while thought, to see  if anybody knows how to do it in lattice or base graphics.

Comment: Realized the [beeswarm package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/beeswarm/index.html) I mentioned above gives uses the standard graphics system, so I already got two good ways to accomplish it.

Comment: To adjust the size of the data points, add a dotsize option to geom_dotplot()